# Problem with the prestashop 1.7.5.2 basket after adding javascript

Tags: javascript, prestashop

Welcome.
I want to change the text from to in the cart and I used javascript for that because I want to have a picture and not text.
http://prntscr.com/p9329t
http://prntscr.com/p932gf
The script works, but as it is added to the page's code, the address and data editing does not work in the cart, after clicking zero errors in the console ... Anyone suggest something?

```
$(document).ready(function podmien() {
    var dopodmiany = 'wybierzpaczkomatbezpo';
    var podmiana = '<a href="/paczkomatymapa.html" target="_blank"><img src="szukajpaczkomatu.jpg"></a>';
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(dopodmiany, podmiana);
});

$(document).ready(function podmien2() {
    var dopodmiany2 = 'wybierzpaczkomatzpo';
    var podmiana2 = '<a href="/paczkomatymapa.html" target="_blank"><img src="szukajpaczkomatu.jpg"></a>';
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(dopodmiany2, podmiana2);
});
```

Comment: with document.body.innerHTML you are replacing the entire page, this make all listener fault.  only act on the Dom node that interests you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but i think you stop the init Jquery by renaming the first function, so you can try this please :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dopodmiany = 'wybierzpaczkomatbezpo';
    var podmiana = '<a href="/paczkomatymapa.html" target="_blank"><img src="szukajpaczkomatu.jpg"></a>';
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(dopodmiany, podmiana);

    var dopodmiany2 = 'wybierzpaczkomatzpo';
    var podmiana2 = '<a href="/paczkomatymapa.html" target="_blank"><img src="szukajpaczkomatu.jpg"></a>';
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(dopodmiany2, podmiana2);
});
```